# Why is there a faint border around the photo?

Tags: html, css, image

I am adding content to this page: http://rouviere.com/index-new and for some reason there is a faint border around the inset photo in the top section.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="illustration">
    <img class="promo" src="http://www.rouviere.com/_photos/slides_photos.jpg" alt="we package it up" />
</div><!-- end #illustration -->

<div class="headline">
    <h2>Photos</h2>
<p id="sub-head">Show the magic of your world with fine photos</p>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
p#sub-head  { font-size: 24px; margin: 0 0 10px 35px; color: #000; }
img.promo   { float: right; margin-right: 20px; z-index: 0;   }
```

I tried adding border: none; to the image but it didn't make any difference.

I would appreciate any guidance towards a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: To the person that downgraded this question. You are missing the point. This forum is a place to ask legitimate questions. I have had several people respond, but no one has fully answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a legitimate question. Google has multiple pages of people asking this same question. It is a Photoshop bug that has been around since CS3, that adds a faint border to images that are down-sampled.

The solution is to remove the background if the image is down-sampled so that the isolated image is on a transparent background.

Answer (score 2):

The border is on the image itself.

[image]

Comment: Yep was just looking at this and saw the same! Here is your answer :)

Comment: I realize that, however, with white on white there shouldn't be a border.

Comment: huh? that faint grey (#f1f1f1) line around the outside of the whole image there, is on the actual image. the only way you'll get rid of that with CSS is to put the image centered in a div that's two pixels smaller on both dimensions..

Comment: Mike, any ideas where the grey line is coming from then? It wasn't added in Photoshop.

Comment: Wouldn't have a clue, mate. Just open it in PS and remove it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found an answer that might work for you.  Use the following code:

border: 0px solid #cccccc !important;

It made it disappear for me, however, if you use the box-shadow function, you'll still see a border space on the side where the shadow renders.

Hope that helps